Can multithreading improve memory access speed
I usually use SIMD and multithreading to optimize the performance of C++ code. Recently, I have found that for memory intensive code, the improvement effect of multithreading is very poor. I wrote a test code:
#include <immintrin.h>
void test_add(float* src1, float* dst, int length, int thread_num) {
    auto task = [&](int offset, int block){
        float* src1_addr = src1 + offset;
        float* dst_addr = dst + offset;
        int main_loop = block >> 3;
        int remain_loop = block - main_loop * 8;
        float coff = 0.1;
       __m256 coff_vct = _mm256_set1_ps(coff);
       for (int i = 0; i < main_loop; i++) {
           __m256 src1_vct = _mm256_loadu_ps(src1_addr);
           src1_vct = _mm256_add_ps(src1_vct, coff_vct); //The proportion of addition instruction time consumption is very small
           _mm256_storeu_ps(dst_addr, src1_vct);
           src1_addr += 8;
           dst_addr += 8;
       }
        for (int i = 0; i < remain_loop; i++) {
            *dst_addr = *src1_addr + coff;
            src1_addr += 1;
            dst_addr += 1;
        }
    };
    
    std::vector<std::future<void> > fus;
    int block_size = length / thread_num;
    for (int i = 0; i < thread_num - 1; i++) {
        int offset = i * block_size;
        fus.push_back(
            std::async(std::launch::async, [=](){ 
                task(offset, block_size);
            })
        );
    }

    int offset = (thread_num - 1) * block_size;
    task(offset, length - offset);

    for (auto& fu : fus) {
        fu.get(); 
    }
}

int test() {

    int length = 768 * 768 * 16 * 8;
    float* src1 = new float[length];
    float* dst = new float[length];

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        src1[i] = i % 255;
        dst[i] = 0;
    }

    int thread_num = 4;
    int loop = 10;
    struct timeval start_time, end_time ;
    gettimeofday(&start_time, NULL);
    for (int i = 0; i < loop; i++) {
        test_add(src1, dst, length, thread_num);
    }
    gettimeofday(&end_time, NULL);
    printf("%d thread_num = %d cost %.2fms\n",length, thread_num, 1000.0 * (end_time.tv_sec - start_time.tv_sec) + (end_time.tv_usec - start_time.tv_usec) / 1000.0f / loop);

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        printf("dst = %.1f, ", dst[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}

I tested three computers and found that multithreading did not significantly improve memory access speed on Mac x86 i7-9750H and Win i5-10400. On the win i5-10400, there is a significant improvement in memory access speed:
mac x86 i7-9750H:

win i5-10400:

win  i7-12650H:

Each CPU core has its own cache, and in my example, there is no issue of multithreading access conflicts. I cannot understand why multithreading cannot improve memory access speed on Mac x86 i7-9750H and Win i5-10400. Is anyone familiar with the underlying principles of this CPU? Or how can I modify the above code to improve the performance of multithreading?Thank you.

Instead of having one core try to access RAM through the bus, you have multiple cores trying to access RAM through the same bus. You'd get better performance by rewriting your code to access data in the stack (eg copies of a single row in a local array), that's probably already in the CPU's cache, instead of using pointers to go to RAM

BTW your code is mixed up C and C++. C++ doesn't use pointer arithmetic and arrays aren't allocated as pointers. The way the code is written, every read operation dereferences a pointer to main RAM. You're already using std::vector elsewhere, so why not use std::vector<float>? If the arrays were copied by value, the processing code would already have a stack-allocated copy of the data to work on.

Note that on typical architectures a single thread can fully saturate the external memory bus.  Using multiple threads causes the pre-fetcher to get "confused" (as it's being required to fetch different regions) and slow down memory access to below single thread performance.  You need to estimate / measure your single thread performance and compare this to the physical limitations of your hardware.

@PanagiotisKanavos still, on the downside, copying a large array means you're copying a large array before doing anything useful. Depending on what's actually done, having shared data means that if one thread has read data, it's already in the cache... does the cache management even make a distinction between "heap" and "stack"? And most of the std::vector is not stored on the stack anyway...

@ChristianStieber you're doing something useful at CPU cache speeds vs RAM bus speeds and avoid contention for RAM access. Data locality offers huge benefits. If you want to get 12x improvement on a 12-core CPU, you need to reduce RAM access as far as possible. Copying one row at a time to a local, stack-allocated variable is fast because the items are sequential and thus will be cached together.

@Panagiotis Kanavos thanks, The actual scenario is shown in the example, with two constraints: 1. The memory block is applied for through new or malloc. 2. Each data will only be accessed once. My description is not accurate enough, it has nothing to do with C++, and using std:: vector does not improve the performance of multithreading in this case.

Based on the above two constraints, how can this example code be modified to improve the performance of multithreading? Or as @RichardCritten said, on most CPUs, single threads have already occupied the memory bus, causing multithreading to be unable to accelerate the sample code.
